# One big image in canvas (need optimize)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hi i have one big image in the canvas it's `10 000~px x 10 000~ px`. I need zoom in/out functions.
Offer me what technology i need use. Maybe i need split into smaller images like a google maps or something else..

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways you could address this issue.

1. Canvas does support the ability to change the size of an image on the fly by calling the drawImage function of the context object.  There are several permutations of this function, the one you want is the one that takes two rectangles and the image object.  The first rectangle will be the position of the image in x, y coordinates and the height and width of the area you want to copy to the canvas object.  The second one will be the destination of the x and y coordinate of where you want to draw it on the canvas and the height and width.

Simple Example Code

```
context.drawImage(srcImage, 0, 0, 10000, 10000, 0, 0, 800, 800);
```

Now then in this example it will take the full image and reduce it down to a 800x800 image.  Be careful when your sizing images because you can majorly distort the image if you don't keep the original aspect ration.

To make a Zoom feature you would then just change the source height and width which would in effect make it "zoom in". For example:

```
context.drawImage(srcImage, 1000, 1000, 2000, 2000, 0, 0, 800, 800);
```

In this example we would take the starting position of the image and move it to a different location in the source image.  Then we would copy a 2000x2000 piece of the image into the same 800x800 canvas object.

2. Now then I do not recommend this approach because it is asking a lot of your users to download this large of a file.  The next few solutions will depend on what scripting language you are using on the back end server.  Most modern languages today have a decent support library to handle images so you can upload the image to the server and make it re-size it for your users.  It might be helpful that the script also creates a re-sized cached version of the original image so that you can speed up server performance.  For instance you could have the JavaScript start downloading the smallest version of the image and as the client request it download then next level of details needed.  Again this could become very bandwidth intensive and slow for your end users.
3. The technique that I see being deployed in Google maps is they break the area you are viewing into blocks and then each block would download separately as you zoom in and out.  You could replicate this technique with AJAX sending the server your current zoom level and image size. This is probably the more complicated version and would require a lot of work not only on the JavaScript but also on the server code that would handle the multiple request for image data which is beyond the scope of this answer.